# Add custom field to category of custom post type

Tags: posts, categories, customization

I want to add a custom field (for a icon) to categories of a custom post type.
I use the default category type and not a own create category taxonomy.

How can I add the custom field only to the category of these custom post types and not to the general categories (for blog posts).

Comment: Hi Zoker, could you provide more details on what you've tried already (and why it didn't work)?